# AngularJS Filter Array of Arrays

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I am trying to create some filters for a website that displays ports. Each array has ports and within that an array of the individual ports.

This is an example of the json.

```
    {
      "cruiseTitle": "Canada/New England",
      "shipName": "Brilliance of the Seas",
      "imageUrl": "#",
      "region": "",
      "StarRating": 4,
      "ports": [
        "Portland, United Kingdom",
        "Halifax, Nova Scotia, Canada",
        "Bar Harbor, Maine",
        "Boston, Massachusetts",
        "Saint John, New Brunswick"
      ],
      "flightsAvailable": true,
      "departureDate": "2014-09-27T23:00:00.000Z",
      "duration": 7,
      "price": 0,
      "isFeatured": false,
      "isLuxury": false
     }
```

This is the angular I am implementing

```
    Ports: 
    <select ng-model="cruise" ng-options="cruise.ports for cruise in gridData.results"></select>
```

This is just returning the array of ports in a long list.
Is there a way to get it to return each of the ports as an option?

Any advice/solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to display a list of ports from different cruises? Shouldn't you first select a cruise and only then display the ports for that specific cruise?

Comment: Could you give the full structure of the JSON, and not just a little snippet. How are we supposed to know what gridData and results are etc.? Even better would be a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code that we can modify directly without losing the time of rewriting your whole data structure. Thanks

Comment: @bmleite We want to display the different ports because there are so many cruises that the user might want to visit a specific port and this will allow them to narrow the search down.

Comment: Hi @MathieuDavid I have supplied the full JSON packet. All I am hoping for is to get a list of all of the ports. I would like to know if this is possible or not. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to create a list of all the ports based on the `gridData.results`:

```
<select ng-model="cruise" ng-options="port for port in getPorts(gridData.results)"></select>
```

And on the controller:

```
  $scope.getPorts = function(cruises) {
    var ports = [];
    angular.forEach(cruises, function(cruise) {
      angular.forEach(cruise.ports, function(port) {
        if (ports.indexOf(port) === -1) {
          ports.push(port);
        }
      });
    });
    return ports;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna populate the ports array, below is the code

```
$scope.gridData = {};
$scope.gridData.results = {
  "shipName": "Brilliance of the Seas",
  "ports": [
    "Portland, United Kingdom",
    "Halifax, Nova Scotia, Canada",
    "Bar Harbor, Maine",
    "Boston, Massachusetts",
    "Saint John, New Brunswick"
  ],
  "isLuxury": false
};

<select ng-model="cruise" ng-options="port for port in gridData.results.ports" ng-init="cruise = gridData.results.ports[0]"></select>
```

Note : You can assign  gridData.results.ports to $scope.ports and just give ng-options="port for port in ports". ng-init is given to initialize the drop down with the first value in array. Please change according to your requirement.